Okay to use dual sink faucet for water filtraton faucet?
Wondering if I can buy a dual sink faucet that has an additional water filtration faucet built in next to the main faucet to accommodate an under sink RO water filtration system?
I'm renting and the sink only has one other hole for dishwasher drainage which I'd prefer not to touch. Required by state code. I'm aware you can install some sort of dual drain and faucet on that side sink hole, but I'm wondering if using the main faucet would be easier. Not liking the idea of combining lines with a dirty water drainage line with my drinking water even though I know it's probably fine if hooked up correctly.
I should point out I only have basic DIY skills for plumbing.

As a renter, you should probably stick to water filtration options that don't involve replacing the plumbing fixtures, unless your landlord approves.

I found this

here https://www.homedecorous.com/Kitchen-Sink-Faucet-with-Pull-Down-Sprayer-S101
The RO drain is a 1/4 inch pipe and it can be easily mounted on existing drain.
